# How to use tikz-timing with clockarrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-timing

I'm using tikz-timing and like to use clockarrows.
But including the library `\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows}` as described in the tikz-timing manual v0.7e doesn't work for me.

I get the error: `Package tikz-timing Error: No tikz-timing library 'clockarrows' found!. \usetikzlibrary`.

How do I fix this? Thanks for your help.

Sample Code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}%[2014/10/29]
%\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows} %This should be enabled
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}        
            \begin{tikztimingtable}[%
                timing/.style={x=4ex,y=3ex},
                timing/rowdist=5ex,
                every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
                %timing/c/arrow tip=latex, %and this set the style
                thick,
                ]
                &1l N(N1) 2C\\
                &2C N(N2) 1c\\
                \extracode
                    \begin{scope}[very thick]
                        \newcommand{\yheight}{3ex};
                        %DRAW
                        \draw [thin, densely dotted,shorten >=-1mm](N1.base) -- ($ (N1.base) + (0,-1ex) $);
                        \draw [thin, densely dotted,shorten >=-1mm](N2.north) -- ($ (N2.base) + (0,\yheight+1ex)$);
                        \draw [<->, >=latex, thin]($ (N1.base) + (0,-1ex) $) -- ($ (N2.base) + (0,\yheight+1ex)$) node[midway, above = 0.2ex] {$T$} ;           
                    \end{scope}
            \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

Before the last update the clockarrows settings worked.

I use now the version tikz-timing (v0.7e).

The tikz library is tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

Update: With the new version of tikz-timing (v0.7f). It all works as expected. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Something wrong appeared to have happened when the latest version was uploaded to CTAN, so the libraries `tikz-timing` provides were not included. The package author is aware of it (https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/tikz-timing/issues/6/tikz-timing-libraries-are-missing-in-tds#comment-None), so presumably it will be fixed soon. As a temporary fix you can get the `.ins` and `.dtx` files from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing, and run `pdflatex tikz-timing.ins` to generate the libraries, which you can place in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

Comment: Yes, somehow my Makefile did not include the libraries in the TDS.ZIP file in my latest upload. The DTX/INS files however generate them ok, but the distributions are using the TDS.ZIP files, I guess.

Comment: I just uploaded the fixed package to CTAN. Should be updateable with your LaTeX distribution today or tomorrow. The files are also available under https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/tikz-timing/downloads/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was a temporary problem caused by a failed upload to CTAN. Updating will fix it.